# How to provide customized colors to TermCloud chart of Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-visualization

I'm using Term Cloud chart and I'm unable to change the colors that are used by default.

Currently, it uses some blue and black shades.

[Code sample](http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/doc.html) that am trying and tried to change color by providing options as

```
var options = {        
    title: '',
    width:200,  height:200,
    color : 'red'               
};
```

Is there any way to change the colors of the terms ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-color` instead of `color`, also if you already have another color applied to the same variable then it will not work.

P.S. use semicolons, not commas.

Answer (score 0):

The TermCloud visapi-gadget includes custom css at http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/tc.css

```
.term-cloud {font-family: arial; font-size: 10px; }
.term-cloud-1 {font-size: 10px; color: #acc1f3; }
.term-cloud-2 {font-size: 14px; color: #86a0dc; }
.term-cloud-3 {font-size: 18px; color: #607ec5; }
.term-cloud-4 {font-size: 22px; color: #264ca2; }
.term-cloud-5 {font-size: 26px; color: #133b97; }
.term-cloud-6 {font-size: 32px; color: #002a8b; }
.term-cloud-7 {font-size: 36px; color: #071a41; }
.term-cloud-8 {font-size: 40px; color: #081122; }
.term-cloud-9 {font-size: 44px; color: #000000; }
.term-cloud-error {font-family: arial; font-size: 10px; color: red; }
.term-cloud-link {text-decoration: none; }
.term-cloud-link:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

You could replace the provided css with your own, specifying your favorite colors. It's a simple enough block that you could just enclose it in `<style>` tags within your html file.